# How are the following factors 'linear'.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

What does it mean for factors to be linear?

Q:

Find the four linear factors of:

$$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$$

I got the following:

$$(z-e^{i \pm {2\pi \over 5}} )(z-e^{i \pm {4\pi\over 5}} )$$

I though factors are taken to be linear if they are simply real 'integers' ? 
An answer as simple as simple as possible would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Linear factors are simply factors of the form $az+b$. Linear referring to the highest degree in $z$ being $1$. You've exactly answered the question (assuming the roots are correct).

Comment: @CameronWilliams I though factors are taken to be linear if they are simply real 'integers' ? As there are complex components of the factors, and not rational, this would still make the factors linear?

Comment: You have the correct answer, but you really should write out all 4 factors.

Comment: @gurjinder I'm not sure where that definition might be coming from, but take the real numbers as an example. For some line $y=ax+b $, (which is linear, in the same sense) you wouldn't expect integer values.

Comment: @AndresMejia thanks, not sure what i was thinking. Perhaps i was just getting confused with the notation and as a result, thought of such fundamental facts incorrectly.

Comment: "Mathematics is the art of giving the same name to different things"-- general confusion with terminology happens to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear factor is a polynomial of degree one, i.e. things like $mz + b$. It appears your answer is correct, but it might be worth while to write it as $$(z - e^{i + \frac{2\pi}{5}})(z - e^{i - \frac{2\pi}{5}})(z - e^{i + \frac{4\pi}{5}})(z - e^{i - \frac{4\pi}{5}})$$ to make it apparent that there are four linear factors.

Edit: Your factorization, as you have it written, is actually incorrect. Multiply out your factorization to see this. I hope this helped answer what a linear factor is and if there is still questions on why your factorization is incorrect, just ask.

Comment: Except you have fallen for the OP's wrong notation - $i+2\pi/5$ is wrong - it should be $\pm i\frac{2\pi}{5}$. Or you could write it as $i(+2\pi/5)$. But as written, it is wrong.

Comment: I recognized this but was just addressing OP's question about what a linear factor is, but I'll edit my answer when I am not on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple: you have a variable plus a constant. This is linear, since the factors are not squared, they're not quadratic etc.

Anything of the form $az+b $ would suffice. It is not as clear by the way you've written your answer, but you have four linear factors, all of the aforementioned form.

Comment: to add to this, notice that the types of numbers that $a,b$ are doesn't matter. They can be complex like your example, as long as they are numbers and don't contain variables themselves then the expression is linear

Comment: Indeed. I want to say that your statement is the reason I didn't specify what set the constants are in. However, in truth, I am using the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Any factor of the form $az+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z$ is the (complex) polynomial variable, is called *polynomial of degree 1* or a *linear factor*.

More generally and related to your example, you have the following: any polynomial of degree $n$ of the form:
$$a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1z+a_0$$
can be written as:
$$a_n(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\ldots\color{blue}{(z-z_i)}\ldots(z-z_n)$$
where the $z_i$'s are the (complex) roots of the polynomial, not necessarily unique.

Every factor of the form "$\color{blue}{(z-z_i)}$" where $z$ is the (polynomial) variable and $z_i \in \mathbb{C}$ is just a complex number, is a polynomial of **degree 1** and thus (by definition) **linear**. The form of the numbers $z_i$ is arbitrary, these don't have to be integers or rational numbers.